# python - Reading a CSV file efficiently and checking for multiple potential errors

Tags: python-3.x

This is my first question on stack overflow. Please ignore any formatting mistakes. I am trying to do these tasks on a CSV file: check for null byte errors (fix them), any other error (raise an exception), check no. of rows (raise exception if none). I am using the below code which is working fine. But I think it's not efficient because I am reading the CSV file twice. Once to replace null bytes and again to check for any other errors. I would like your help on making this code efficient. I want to go through the file only once but make sure I finish all the above tasks. Thanks in advance!

output is the csv file

```
if (any(x in lines[i] for x in ['drop table', 'create table'])):
    os.remove(output)
else:
    with open(output, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader((line.replace('\0','') for line in f) )
        try:
            for row in reader:
                pass
            try:
                row_count = sum(1 for each in open(output))     
                if row_count != 1:
                    print('Data Fetched into ' + output + ' with ' + str(row_count-1) + ' rows')
                else:
                    raise NoDataFetched
            except NoDataFetched:
                print("No data is fetched. Please check your query")    
        except csv.Error as e:
            print('file %s, line %d: %s' % (output, reader.line_num, e))
```

Comment: `for row in reader: pass`. Why are you doing that?

Comment: I don't want to do anything if the row read successfully. If any error, exception should catch it at that line and exit the program.